# HTML/CSS table vertical margin

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding, margin

I used a Python library to generate the following HTML code. What CSS property can I use to increase the space between rows? I tried to set the margin and padding properties of the `tr` and `th` elements but it didn't work.

```
<style  type="text/css" >
    #T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122 th.col_heading {
          text-align: center;;
    }    #T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122 th.col_heading.level0 {
          font-size: 1.5em;;
    }    #T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122 td {
          border: solid 1px #000;;
          padding: 10px;;
    }    #T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122 th {
          border: solid 1px #000;;
    }    #T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122 tr {
          margin: 0px 10px;
    }#T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122row0_col0,#T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122row1_col0,#T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122row2_col0{
            background-color:  LightGreen;
        }</style><table id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122" ><thead>    <tr>        <th class="blank" ></th>        <th class="blank" ></th>        <th class="blank level0" ></th>        <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >color</th>    </tr>    <tr>        <th class="index_name level0" >id</th>        <th class="index_name level1" >type</th>        <th class="index_name level2" >options</th>        <th class="blank" ></th>    </tr></thead><tbody>
                <tr>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level0_row0" class="row_heading level0 row0" >id1</th>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level1_row0" class="row_heading level1 row0" >machine</th>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level2_row0" class="row_heading level2 row0" >-</th>
                        <td id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level0_row1" class="row_heading level0 row1" >id2</th>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level1_row1" class="row_heading level1 row1" >machine</th>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level2_row1" class="row_heading level2 row1" >-</th>
                        <td id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >green</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level0_row2" class="row_heading level0 row2" >id3</th>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level1_row2" class="row_heading level1 row2" >machine</th>
                        <th id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122level2_row2" class="row_heading level2 row2" >-</th>
                        <td id="T_5c9d5f2c_dea4_11eb_bdfd_acde48001122row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >green</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Thank you!

Comment: why are you giving id in such a complex way? :(

Comment: That's generated by the Python code.

Comment: Okay okay, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table rows cannot have margin values. Can you increase the padding? That would work. Otherwise you could insert a `<tr class="spacer"></tr>` before and after the `class="highlighted"` rows.

Or

The `border-spacing` property will work for this particular case.

```
table {
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can just edit the CSS code. Did you have a chance to try it? It does not seem to work.

Comment: It works for me, I hope for you too, the problem is that the codes are not so flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding style class to a table. You will need to add "border-collapse" and "border-spacing" it should look something like this if you want just space between rows:

```
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:  0 15px;
```

and something like this if you want space between rows and columns:

```
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:  15px;
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you have a chance to try it? It does not seem to work.

Comment: I did try it, and it does work for me. Have you resolved your issue?